# Google Maps API v3, Ground Overlay not positioning image tag correctly

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am experiencing a strange positioning issue when placing an overlay in my home city (Syracuse, NY).  First the test map:

http://hotsdg.com/~downtown/map.html

This map uses the example code to place my image over newark.  No problem here.  The image is skewed and distorted of course, by placement occurs as expected.

The second map:

http://hotsdg.com/~downtown/map_two.html

This map uses the example code with coords adjusted to place the image over Syracuse, NY.  At first glance the overlay appears to be missing.  However, upon inspection I discovered that the  element which is used for the overlay has it's top set to 94px (at the initial zoom), instead of 0px.  Adjusting this manually brings the image into view.

Any thoughts as to what might be happening here, or more importantly, why it's happening?

Comment: Hi Todd, welcome to Stack Overflow. Try posting some code in your question to make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [google.maps.LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) takes SW, NE LatLngs for the constructor.

Your working map does that (SW, NE):

```
        var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
              new google.maps.LatLng(40.716216, -74.213393),
              new google.maps.LatLng(40.765641, -74.139235));
```

the not working one is (NW, SE):

```
        var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(43.054340, -76.159101),
                new google.maps.LatLng(43.042504, -76.142601));
```

Comment: Wow, what a noob-error.  I thought it might have been a 'too long staring at code today' mistake.  Thanks geocodezip!